# Error while adding ImageView[] array to BorderPane in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, illegalargumentexception

I made an `ImageView` array:

```
public static ImageView[] array = new ImageView[2];
```

Then set the `ImageView`:

```
ImageView img = new ImageView(new Image("sample.png"));
array [0] = img;
array [1] = img;
```

Then add it to the screen:

```
root.getChildren().add(array [0]);
root.getChildren().add(array [1]);
```

**ERROR:**

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Children: duplicate children added: parent = BorderPane@78e30575
```

So, where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message really says it all. You can't add the same child twice, and in your snippet both `array[0]` and `array[1]` point to the same object. You could, however, add two objects that use the same image:

```java
array[0] = new ImageView(new Image("sample.png"));
array[1] = new ImageView(new Image("sample.png"));
```

Comment: It would be more efficient to have 2 ImageViews, but only one Image.  It is only the duplicate node (InageView) which is causing the error.  If you have two different nodes, but point them both to the same Image, that won’t be a problem and is preferred.